# LDAP authentication in Java

Tags: spring, authentication, ldap

I need to connect to LDAP server, but I'm getting the following error:

javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, vece

Username and password are correct, I've tried to set the same user and pass in another application written in .NET and it works there, but in Java I am getting error message.

My code is:

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(ModelMap model) {

```
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://subdomain.domain.com:389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=username,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=com");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");


    InitialDirContext context;

    try 
    {
        context = new InitialDirContext(env);
    } 

    catch (NamingException e1) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I would ask someone who has working code to post it here.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Active Directory does not work with UIDs
2. Don't supply a DN as username but your regular user principal name for logging it.

Comment: Do you mean this: env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, domain username);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

Answer (score 0):

A DN will work fine, IF the [DN is correct](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Determining%20the%20FDN).

error code 49 - ... data 525 implies LDAP_NO_SUCH_OBJECT (Entry does not exist.)

I doubt that "uid=username,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=com" is a good DN.